# I am trying to dynamiclly set state based on a set of values

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have these checkboxes that i am controlling the state by their ID  but i am getting error that i am using an uncontrolled component because the state is not initially set. I am trying to render the state based on unknown values.

i am trying to do something like this

I am trying to set initial state dynamically

```
const [deliveredBoxes, setDelivered] = useState({
    orders.map((order, i) => {
      [order.transactionID]: order.orderDelivered
    })
});
```

> Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

This is what i came up with although the initial state is still not being set

```
        const [deliveredBoxes, setDelivered] = useState([]);
         useEffect(() => {
          orders.map((order, i) => {
          setDelivered({
        ...deliveredBoxes,
        [order.transactionID]: order.orderDelivered
           });
       });
      }, []);
```

Comment: to reference keys dynamically you need array bracket syntax around the variables. `orders.map((order, i) => { [order.transactionID]: order.orderDelivered })`

Comment: this still isnt working im getting syntax errors :(

Comment: You need parentheses around the brackets to denote an inline object. `orders.map((order, i) => ({ [order.transactionID]: order.orderDelivered }))`

Comment: Would be good to post more context and or something that replicates the issue so we can test it for u.

Comment: updated the question for you

Comment: You try to put an array into `useState()` object `{}` argument. It simply cannot be done. Provide key eg `{ orders: orders.map...}`

Comment: What are you suggesting i do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your code like below.

**Solution 1:** Simply add `(` in `map` function.

```
const [deliveredBoxes, setDelivered] = useState({
  orders.map((order, i) => (
    {
       [order.transactionID]: order.orderDelivered
    }
  ));
});
```

**Solution 2:** Add `{` and return the `object` in `map` function.

```
const [deliveredBoxes, setDelivered] = useState({
  orders.map((order, i) => {
    return {
      [order.transactionID]: order.orderDelivered
    }
  })
});
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Im still getting the same Error for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use another hook useEffect.
Please try this whether this works.

```
const [deliveredBoxes, setDelivered] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
 orders.map((order, i) => {
      [order.transactionID]: order.orderDelivered
}
setDelivered(orders);
, [])
```